# How to convert & characters to HTML characters?

Tags: php, html, string, html-entities

`&lt;?php echo "Hello World!"; ?&gt;`

should be:

`<?php echo "Hello World!"; ?>`

How do I do that in PHP?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need one of these:

```
html_entity_decode()
htmlspecialchars_decode()
```

- [html_entity_decode() in PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)
- [htmlspecialchars_decode() in PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)

The main difference is that `html_entity_decode()` will translate all the HTML entities in your string (`&lt;` becomes `<`, `&aacute;` becomes `á`, etc.) while `html_specialchars_decode()` only translates some special HTML entities:

> The converted entities are: `&amp;`, `&quot;` (when ENT_NOQUOTES is not
>   set), `&#039;` (when ENT_QUOTES is set), `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Answer (score 6):

[`htmlspecialchars_decode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [`html_entity_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)?

Answer (score 0):

If you're actually trying to do this manually, instead of with [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php), try [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

```
$needle = array("&lt;","&gt;");
$replace = array("<", ">");
$string = '&lt;?php echo "Hello World!"; ?&gt;';

$string = str_replace($needle, $replace, $string);

print $string; // prints <?php echo "Hello World!"; ?>
```

Comment: @downvoter I fail to see how this answer is sloppy, dangerously wrong, or no effort expended. Please [use down votes properly](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)