# Split an array by first letter containing html entity

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8, html-entities

I've got an array with countries like this

```
array(249) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["country_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["country_name_en"]=>
    string(19) "&Aring;land Islands"
    ["country_alpha2"]=>
    string(2) "AX"
    ["country_alpha3"]=>
    string(3) "ALA"
  }
  etc.
}
```

I would like to split it by the first letter so i get an array like this

```
array(26) {
 'A' => array(10) {
    array(4) {
      ["country_id"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["country_name_en"]=>
      string(19) "&Aring;land Islands"
      ["country_alpha2"]=>
      string(2) "AX"
      ["country_alpha3"]=>
      string(3) "ALA"
    }
    etc.
  }
  etc.
}
```

But the problem is that the array of country names contains html entities as first character.

Any ideas how to do this?

thanks in advance

Peter

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert & characters to HTML characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665985/how-to-convert-characters-to-html-characters)

Comment: As this question requires the transliteration of `Å` to `A`, I don't think @Gordon's suggestion of a duplicate is fitting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to transliterate Accented Characters into plain ascii chars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542717/how-to-transliterate-accented-characters-into-plain-ascii-characters)

Answer (score 2):

If you want `Åland Islands` to be filed under `A`, you'll need to do a bit more than the already suggested [html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/html_entity_decode).

[intl](http://php.net/intl) contains the [Normalizer::normalize()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/normalizer.normalize.php), a function to convert `Å` to `Å`. Confused yet? That unicode symbol (U+00C5) can be represented as `0xC385` (Composition) and `0x41CC8A` (Decomposition) in UTF-8. `0x41` is `A`, `0xCC8A` is `̊`.

So, to get your islands filed properly, you'd want to do something like this:

```
$string = "&Aring;land Islands";
$s = html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$s = Normalizer::normalize($s, Normalizer::FORM_KD);
$s = mb_substr($s, 0, 1);
```

Chances are, your environment doesn't have [intl](http://php.net/intl) installed. If that's the case, you might look into [urlify()](https://gist.github.com/909692), a function that will reduce strings to their alphanumeric parts.

---

with the above you should be able to

1. loop the original array
2. extract the country name
3. sanitize the country name and extract the first character
4. build a new array based on the character of (3)

Note: Beware that the countries `Armenia`, `Austria` and `Australia` would all file under `A`.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the array, use [html_entity_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) to decode the html entities, and then split using [mb_substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php).

```
foreach($array as $values) {
    $values['country_name_en'] = html_entity_decode($values['country_name_en']);
    $index = mb_substr($values['country_name_en'], 0, 1);

    $new_array[$index] = $values;
}
```

---

Or you can use the function jlcd suggested:

```
function substr_unicode($str, $s, $l = null) {
    return join("", array_slice(
        preg_split("//u", $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY), $s, $l));
}

foreach($array as $values) {
    $values['country_name_en'] = html_entity_decode($values['country_name_en']);
    $index = substr_unicode($values['country_name_en'], 0, 1);

    $new_array[$index] = $values;
}
```

Comment: Be aware that, when using `mb_substr` or `substr`, it may not return the proper result depending on the string's encoding: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php#107698